# Emmet custom snippet

Tags: emmet, adobe-brackets

I am trying to code a custom snippet for Emmet, and am not getting the result I want. I am trying to output this:

```
<perch:every count=" "></perch:every>
```

With a cursor between the quote marks and then between the tags. How would I go about this? Does it need to be an abbreviation rather than a snippet?

I have this so far:

```
{
"html": {
"abbreviations": {
    "perchafter":"<perch:after>",
    "perchbefore":"<perch:before>"
    },

  "snippets": {
    "perchcontent": "<?php perch_content('|'); ?>"
    "perchevery": "<perch:every count="|"></perch:every>"
}


  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should post your snippets.json file contents first.

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok please see edit to original question

Comment: The JSON above is invalid because there’s no comma after `"<?php perch_content('|'); ?>"`